# $ \int \bigl| a\sin(x)+b\cos(x) \bigr| {\rm d}x = ? $

Tags: calculus, integration, indefinite-integrals, absolute-value, trigonometric-integrals

> My friend evaluated this to be
>   $$
> \int \bigl| a\sin(x)+b\cos(x) \bigr| {\rm d}x \\
> = \sqrt{a^2+b^2} \left( 
> \sin(x-\phi)\text{sign}(\cos(x-\phi))
> +\frac{2}{\pi} \bigl(x-\arctan(\tan(x-\phi)) \bigr)
> \right) + C
> $$
>   where $\phi = \arctan \left(\frac{a}{b} \right)$.

My answer instead is much shorter, by simply looking for the intervals of $x$ for which I need to multiply by $-1$, I got

$$
(b\sin(x)-a\cos(x)) \cdot \text{sign}(a\sin(x)+b\cos(x)) + C
$$

Why does my friend's solution look so big and complex and how did she even come up with the idea to do that?

Comment: Try $b=1$, $a=0$, then you suggest $\sin x\cdot\text{sign}\,\cos x$ as the antiderivative, but it is not even continuous at some points.

Comment: What exactly is the point of the $\frac{\sqrt{\cos^2(x-\phi)}}{\cos(x-\phi)}$? It could be replaced by $\text{sign}(\cos(x-\phi))$.

Comment: @A.Γ. The other solution actually also gives $\sin x \cdot \text{sign} \cos x$ in that case

Comment: @JohnDoe Not really, it has the extra term with $\arctan$ that shifts the function in different intervals by a multiple of $2$ to make it continuous.

Comment: @A.Γ. Ah yes, you're right.

Comment: @JohnDoe It is funny that WolframAlpha gives the [same discontinuous function](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=plot+sin+x*sgn(cos+x)) as the [answer](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=integrate+abs(cos+x)).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

She is probably starting by replacing the $a\sin x + b\cos x$ and rewriting in terms of a function with an amplitude and phase. One way to do this is to multiply by $1$ and draw a right triangle with angle $\phi$, adjacent side length $b$, and opposite side length $a$. Then one has

$$\begin{aligned} \left|a\sin x + b\cos x\right| &= \sqrt{a^{2}+b^{2}}\left|\frac{a}{\sqrt{a^{2}+b^{2}}}\,\sin x + \frac{b}{\sqrt{a^{2}+b^{2}}}\,\cos x\right| \\
&= \sqrt{a^{2}+b^{2}}\left|\sin\phi\sin x + \cos\phi\cos x\right| \\
&= \sqrt{a^{2}+b^{2}}\left|\cos(x-\phi)\right|.\end{aligned}$$

This procedure is motivated in physics/engineering as a more elegant way of writing solutions to the harmonic oscillator equation, as amplitude and phase both have physical interpretations and are often easier to determine given initial conditions.